# Vue3: Unable to access proxy's target data

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

This is my first question so I'll try to explain the problem as much as I can.

I'm working on a Vue3 project, where I have a component that receives props, these props are treated as proxys in Vue (reactivity purposes).

The problem comes when reading the data. The proxy's target seems to have data, but when console.log() the object.property, shows undefined:

[console.log(this.slideResults)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5GxH.png)

[console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.slideResults)))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Ak6.png)

My component:

```
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        takenImage: HTMLImageElement,
        slideResults: Object, // slideResults = {[opencvResults], [possibleDuplicatedImages]}
    },
    components: { Swiper, Slide, SwiperSlide },
    computed: {
        getImages() {
            // console.log the prop -> target = Object{canvasResults: canvas, possibleDuplicatedImages: }
            console.log(this.slideResults);

            const slideResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.slideResults));

            console.log(slideResults);

            console.log(slideResults.canvasResults);
            console.log(slideResults.possibleDuplicatedImages);

            // To destructure props and don't lose reactivity we need to convert them into ref
            // const { slideResults } = toRaw(this.slideResults);

            // console.log(slideResults);

            // const { canvasResults, possibleDuplicatedImages } = toRaw(
            //     this.slideResults
            // );

            // console.log(canvasResults[0]);
            // console.log(this.takenImage);

            // // In order to pass to a slide the images as: Array<Object> where [{imageFile, canvas}]
            // /**
            //  * @type {Array<{ image: HTMLCanvasElement[], opencvResult: File[] }>}
            //  */
            const images = [];
            // for (let i = 0; i < canvasResults.length; i++) {
            //     images.push({
            //         image: possibleDuplicatedImages[i],
            //         opencvResult: canvasResults[i],
            //     });
            // }
            // console.log(images);
            return images;
        },
    },
});
```

I have also tried with this, where the logs return the same as above:

```
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        takenImage: HTMLImageElement,
        slideResults: Object, // slideResults = {[opencvResults], [possibleDuplicatedImages]}
    },
    components: { Swiper, Slide, SwiperSlide },
    setup(props) {
        /**
         * Returns the images to use in the slides
         */
        const getImages = () => {
            // To destructure props and don't lose reactivity we need to convert them into ref
            const { slideResults } = toRefs(props);
            const { canvasResults, possibleDuplicatedImages } = toRaw(
                slideResults.value
            );

            console.log(canvasResults);
            console.log(possibleDuplicatedImages);
            console.log(props.takenImage);

            // In order to pass to a slide the images as: Array<Object> where [{imageFile, canvas}]
            /**
             * @type {Array<{ image: HTMLCanvasElement[], opencvResult: File[] }>}
             */
            const images = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < canvasResults.length; i++) {
                images.push({
                    image: possibleDuplicatedImages[i],
                    opencvResult: canvasResults[i],
                });
            }
            console.log(images);
            return images;
        };

        return {
            modules: [Autoplay, Keyboard, Pagination, Zoom, Navigation],
            getImages,
        };
    },
});
```